# Installed bugzilla, getting 404 from apache

Tags: apache2, bugzilla

Thanks for looking at my question.

I installed Ubuntu (14.04) on VM VirtualBox, set it up to serve with apache2, works great. I can get pages to serve.

I installed bigzilla with apt-get install bugzilla3. it walked me through the config. everything seems fine.

localhost/bugzilla returns 404.

I tried adding to apache2.conf:

```
Alias /bugzilla/ /usr/share/bugzilla3/web/
<directory /usr/share/bugzilla3/web>
    Addhandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    AllowOverride Limit
</directory>
```

That doesn't work either. To be fair, when I add aliases to Apache they never work.